# How to catch the azure blob reference when uploading

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I am trying to design a simple view for uploading a file into an azure storage container. Upon upload I want to catch the BlockBlobReference for the uploaded file, store the reference in a database field in order to be able to download the file for later use.
I have realized the view and the controller for uploading (the upload works), but I have no idea how to tackl the rest.

Here is part of my razor view:

```
    <div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadTestFile", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
    <span>Select File:</span>
    <input type="file" name="loadedFiles" multiple />
    <hr />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    <br />
    <span style="color:green">@ViewBag.Message</span>
    }
</div>
```

And this is the controller and the method:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public void UploadTestFile(HttpPostedFileBase loadedFiles)
    {
        string containerName = "testcontainer";
        UploadFileToBlobStorage(containerName, loadedFiles);
    }

    public void UploadFileToBlobStorage(string containerName, HttpPostedFileBase loadedFiles)
    {
        // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

        // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        container.SetPermissions(
            new BlobContainerPermissions
            {
                PublicAccess =
                    BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
            });

// here I would like to iterate through the items, in case that more than one file was selected
// I don't know how to iterate through loadedFiles though


     // filename
        string _fileName = loadedFiles.FileName;


        // Retrieve reference to a blob 
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob =  container.GetBlockBlobReference(_fileName);

            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(loadedFiles.InputStream);
    }
```

Could someone help me or give me some hints, please.
Regards, Manu

Comment: Why would you want to store the BlobReference? You can always download the file with just the name and the container name.

Comment: @Matias: Thanks for the hint. I did not know that only the container and filename suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely store just the file name (and the container name in case it can change) or the url (depending on whether the container is public or not).

If the **container is public**, you can simply use the blob url: `https://{yourstorageaccount}.blob.core.windows.net/{container}/{filename.extension}`.

If its **private**, you can store the filename and read the file like this:

```
public byte[] ReadFile(string containerName, string fileName)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    var fileBase = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
    if (!fileBase.Exists())
    {
        return null;
    }
    fileBase.FetchAttributes();
    var fileByteLength = fileBase.Properties.Length;
    var fileByteArray = new Byte[fileByteLength];

    fileBase.DownloadToByteArray(fileByteArray, 0);
    return fileByteArray;
}
```

Or like this if you want the content as a string:

```
public string ReadFileAsString(string containerName, string fileName)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    var fileBase = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
    if (!fileBase.Exists())
    {
        return null;
    }
    return fileBase.DownloadText(Encoding.UTF8, AccessCondition.GenerateEmptyCondition(), null, null);
}
```

If you want to trigger a download from an MVC Action, you can do something like:

```
public ActionResult GetFile(string fileName)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("myContainer");
    var fileBase = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
    if (!fileBase.Exists())
    {
        return null;
    }
    fileBase.FetchAttributes();
    var fileByteLength = fileBase.Properties.Length;
    var fileByteArray = new Byte[fileByteLength];

    fileBase.DownloadToByteArray(fileByteArray, 0);

    return File(fileByteArray, fileBase.Properties.ContentType, fileName);
}
```

Comment: That code is helpful. But regarding the download: I meant to present a download link on a razor view to the previously stored file in order to enable the user to download it. How do I get the url (as a variable) into the razor view? (I do not need to download the file for myself). And how must the controller look like (in case that I need any at all) to start the download?

Comment: Is the container public?

Comment: yes. but later I want to do the same thing with SAS

Comment: Added a code sample of an MVC Action downloading the file. You can point to it from the View with an anchor tag `<a target="_blank" href="/somecontroller/getfile?fileName=TheFileName"></a>`.

Comment: Many thanks again. This will keep me bussy for a while trying to understand and implement it. In case that I fail, I will ask again  :)